# How to get stack dump from crashing ASP.NET process?

Tags: asp.net, iis

> An unhandled exception
>   ('System.Net.Sockets.SocketException')
>   occurred in w3wp.exe [9740].
>   Just-In-Time debugging this exception
>   failed with the following error:
>   Debugger could not be started because
>   no user is logged on.

We're getting the above error in the Application log. Is there a way to capture a .NET stack trace that doesn't require user interactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the article [Catch Exceptions on x64](http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2008/04/27/catch-exceptions-on-x64.aspx), this will work fine on x86 as well.